# change status code of Response in @angular/ssr in angular 17

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-ssr

new method of ssr introduced in angular 17. how can i change status code of express response in angular components now?
previously i changed the response like this:

```
import { RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { Response } from 'express';  

constructor(@Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: Response)


this.response.status(this.statusCode);
```

with this i could change the status code. for example if i met the not-found component i had to change the status code to 404 for SEO reasons.

Answer (score 5):

The tokens aren't exported anymore by `@angular/ssr`.

What the migration schematics currently does is that is creates them :

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
export const REQUEST = new InjectionToken<Request>('REQUEST');
export const RESPONSE = new InjectionToken<Response>('RESPONSE');
```

An you'll need to provide them :
It could look something like that :

```
export function app(): express.Express {
    documentFilePath: indexHtml,
    url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
    publicPath: distFolder,
    providers: [
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl },
      { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res },
      { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req })
   ],
}
```

[Here is the PR](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/26175/files) that introduced that improvement for the schematics

Also as a note, `ng serve` doesn't use `server.ts` (it doesn't use express. The recommended approach to treat the tokens set in `server.ts` as optional.

Comment: thanks for sharing. i could provide them but i got an error when i want inject them in not-found component for instance. how can i inject them and where should i create these tokens?

Comment: see my update, you can only use them in prod  with express. The devServer doesn't rely on it !

Answer (score 1):

You should create src/express.token.ts with this code :

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
export const REQUEST = new InjectionToken<Request>('REQUEST');
export const RESPONSE = new InjectionToken<Response>('RESPONSE');
```

In server.ts and in your component use :

```
import {RESPONSE} from "./src/express.tokens";
import {REQUEST} from "./src/express.tokens";
```

Answer (score 0):

this is important for resolve this problem

> Also as a note, ng serve doesn't use server.ts (it doesn't use
> express. The recommended approach to treat the tokens set in server.ts
> as optional.

to test

You need to build your app and than serve it, If try to do this thing using ng serve, It will not work

Answer (score -3):

The dev environment is the problem which `ng server` totally ignores `server.ts`
Related issue on github:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26323
Now it has `freq3: high` label (many people faced the same issue)

Comment: my problem is related to production environment. thanks.

Comment: You want to debug your app on production? amazing! :)

Comment: We have more environments than development and production. Before deployment, testing is done in other environments.